# R - summarizing /collapsing observations by selecting the maximum value of a streak

Tags: r, dplyr

Im working on the following idea. Hope you can help.

***UPDATED***

I have added a third subject which illsutrates the problem

**DATA**

```
reprex <- structure(list(record_id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3), day = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
10, 11, 12), rx_class = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 0), streak = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 
1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 
1), last_stop = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1
), reason = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 
2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 4), 
    reason_text = c(NA, "diarrhea", NA, NA, "recover", NA, "diarrhea", 
    NA, "recover", "vomiting", NA, NA, NA, NA, "sweating", NA, 
    "recover", NA, NA, NA, "diarrhea", NA, NA, "recover", "diarrhea", 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, "recover", NA, NA, "diarrhea", NA, "recover", 
    "vomiting")), row.names = c(NA, -36L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**EXPLANATION**
As you can see, we now follow the treatment journey of three subjects for 12 days. Treatment (`rx_class` = 1/2/3) can be stopped (`rx_class` = 0) for a brief moment or permanently. The variable `streak` counts the days without treatment, and `last_stop` marks whether this stop is permanent (`last_stop` = 1; no treatment resumed in the future). `reason` and `reason_text` explain why the treatment was stopped.

**AIM**
I want to summarize all streaks of treatment interruption or permanent discontinuation in the following output

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
reprex_output <- structure(list(record_id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), interruption_no = c(1, 
2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3), day = c(2, 7, 10, 3, 9, 1, 9, 12), streak = c(3, 
2, 3, 2, 3, 5, 2, 1), last_stop = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), 
    reason = c(1, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 4), reason_text = c("diarrhea", 
    "diarrhea", "vomiting", "sweating", "diarrhea", "diarrhea", 
    "diarrhea", "vomiting")), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

> reprex_output
# A tibble: 8 x 7
  record_id interruption_no   day streak last_stop reason reason_text
      <dbl>           <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>      
1         1               1     2      3         0      1 diarrhea   
2         1               2     7      2         0      1 diarrhea   
3         1               3    10      3         1      4 vomiting   
4         2               1     3      2         0      3 sweating   
5         2               2     9      3         0      2 diarrhea   
6         3               1     1      5         0      1 diarrhea   
7         3               2     9      2         0      1 diarrhea   
8         3               3    12      1         1      4 vomiting
```

**CURRENT PROBLEM**
When I use the suggested code down below, it works fine for the first two subjects. However, subject 3 starts with an interruption. As you can see, the output is partially correct for subject 3: the `interruption_no` does not count properly, but the second and third interruption gets skipped.

```
# A tibble: 6 x 7
# Groups:   record_id [3]
  record_id interruption_no   day streak last_stop reason reason_text
      <dbl>           <int> <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>      
1         1               1     2      3         0      1 diarrhea   
2         1               2     7      2         0      1 diarrhea   
3         1               3    10      3         1      4 vomiting   
4         2               1     3      2         0      3 sweating   
5         2               2     9      3         0      1 diarrhea   
6         3              NA     1      5         0      1 diarrhea
```

BW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the most elegant solution, but may be helpful.

You can use `cumsum` to group by interruption, where `rx_class` changes from some value to zero over time. This will be helpful in grouping these epidodes/streaks together.

You can remove `rx_class` afterwards with `filter`, since only interested in interruption data.

Then, you can `group_by` both the `record_id` and our newly created group to `summarise`. The `streak` would be the `max` value for a given interruption. It also will use the first row of each subgroup to determine other column values.

**Edit**: In cases where there isn't a treatment prior to a record of stopping a treatment, include in `lag` a `default` (perhaps some value to represent an "unknown" treatment, but to demonstrate I put in a default of 1).

```
library(tidyverse)

reprex %>%
  group_by(record_id) %>%
  mutate(interruption_no = cumsum(lag(rx_class, default = 1) != 0 & rx_class == 0)) %>%
  filter(rx_class == 0) %>%
  group_by(record_id, interruption_no) %>%
  summarise(day = first(day),
            streak = max(streak),
            last_stop = first(last_stop),
            reason = first(reason),
            reason_text = first(reason_text))
```

**Output**

```
  record_id interruption_no   day streak last_stop reason reason_text
      <dbl>           <int> <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>      
1         1               1     2      3         0      1 diarrhea   
2         1               2     7      2         0      1 diarrhea   
3         1               3    10      3         1      4 vomiting   
4         2               1     3      2         0      3 sweating   
5         2               2     9      3         0      1 diarrhea   
6         3               1     1      5         0      1 diarrhea   
7         3               2     9      2         0      1 diarrhea   
8         3               3    12      1         1      4 vomiting
```

Comment: Hi Ben. This is certainly on track. Still scanning whether this works sufficiently. I noticed that when day 1 already starts with a 0 (so no treatment), the interruption_no counter doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Great - as you check it over, feel free to edit your example with other cases where there may be issues, and what your expected output would be in those cases...we may need a default for `lag`...

Comment: Hi Ben, I think I have summarised the issue now properly

Comment: @GI-DEON6 Please see edited answer. Try adding `default = 1` to `lag` to account for situations where this isn't a "prior row" value available for `rx_class` (situations where the treatment is unknown prior to stopping)....

Comment: It was what you had predicted. Thanks a lot :)